# How to scale max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm running a somewhat large Kafka cluster, but currently I'm stuck at properly setting `max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots` and would need some guidance. The documentation about this is not clear either: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-227%3A+Introduce+Incremental+FetchRequests+to+Increase+Partition+Scalability

By scale i mean: 3 nodes, ~400 Topics, 4500 Partitions, 300 consumergroups, 500 consumers

For a while now, I'm seeing the `FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND` errors appearing in the logs and wanted to address them.

So I've tried increasing the value in the config, restarted all brokers and the pool quickly filled up again to it's max capacity. This reduced the occurrence of the errors, but they are not completely gone. At first I've set to value to 2000, it was instantly full. Then in several steps up to 100.000. And the pool was filled in ~40 Minutes.

From the documentation I was expecting the pool to cap out after 2 Minutes when `min.incremental.fetch.session.eviction.ms` kicks in. But this seems not to be the case.

What would be the metrics to gauge the appropriate size of the cache. Are the errors I'm still seeing anything I can fix on the brokers or do I need to hunt down misconfigured consumers? If so, what do I need to look out for?

Comment: Are any of the Consumers using the Sarama (golang) client? A recent version of this Kafka client had a bug that caused it to create a new FetchSession on every poll. See https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/pull/1644
Otherwise apart from a malicious client, I can't quite see how 500 consumers could use 100000 FetchSessions

Comment: @MickaelMaison yes, in fact half of the consumers are using sarama. I'll take a look at these issues and try to update them. Thank you very much for that suggestion!

Comment: @MickaelMaison I've now confirmed, that Sarama is the culprit here. If you post it as an answer, I'll gladly mark it as answered.

To validate this: tcpdump the traffic on port 9092, open with Wireshark and filter for `kafka.fetch_session_epoch == 0`. If a client is showing up excessively, it might be affected. (It's very helpful if you set ClientID in your services to have them represented nicely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a high usage of Fetch Sessions is most likely caused by a bad client.

[Sarama](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama), a Golang client, had an issue that caused a new Fetch Session to be allocated on every Fetch request between versions 1.26.0 and 1.26.2, see https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/pull/1644.

I'd recommend checking if you have users running this client and ensure they update to the latest release.